# Alguém pode ajudar em uma resolução de um código em C?

Tags: c

Galera seguinte, estou estudando e sou Iniciante, e tenho essa resolução para resolver e estou com dificuldade... tenho que utilizar `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", s)`, onde `s` é um array de `char`...
O código tem que ler dois dados do terminal, um conjunto de caracteres (de até 100 caracteres) e um valor inteiro e os exiba no console.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char s[100];

    printf("Nome\n");
    printf("3");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", s);
    return 0;
}
```

O código é tipo esse que coloquei, eu consegui fazer ele ler os dados, no caso `nome` e `3` como padrão, por que não é preciso o usuário digitar, mais a parte do `scanf` eu não consigo.

**A Entrada de dados tem que ser já digitada no código igual ta alie em cima, pois as partes do printf ta certa.**

nome

3

**Saída esperada um abaixo do outro assim mas a saida não da isso automático...**

nome

3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria isso ?

```
int main(void){
  char s[100];
  int numero; 

printf("Entre com o numero:");

scanf("%d", &numero);

printf("Entre com os caracteres:");

scanf(" %99[^\n]", s);

printf("%s", s);

printf("\n %d",numero);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: int main()
{
char s[100];

printf("nome\n");
printf("3");
scanf(" %[^\n]", s);
return 0;
} 
é tipo assim mano, só que não sei como exibir o mesmo valor depois com o scanf

Answer (score 1):

Tarefa simples.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int numero;
  char nome[100];

  printf("*\n");

  printf("* digite nome: ");
  scanf("%99[^\n]", nome);

  printf("* digite numero: ");
  scanf("%d", &numero);

  printf("*\n");

  printf("* nome digitado: [%s]\n", nome);
  printf("* numero digitado: [%d]\n", numero);

  printf("*\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Compilação e teste no Linux:

```
[~/Projects/testes/so]
$cc 397063.c

[~/Projects/testes/so]
$mv a.out 397063

[~/Projects/testes/so]
$./397063 
*
* digite nome: aaa bbb
* digite numero: 123
*
* nome digitado: [aaa bbb]
* numero digitado: [123]
*

[~/Projects/testes/so]
$
```